# Turning categorized output into continuous

Tags: bayesian, naive-bayes, javascript

I'm using a NaiveBayes algorithm that generates categorized probabilities as output instead of continuous values, which is what I need for this webapp I'm working on. Unfortunately I can't switch algorithms right now, what would be the most adequate way/formula at this point to turn the output into a single real number?

The data looks like this (Javascript object):

```
{
    14:0.01,
    15:0.02,
    17:0.04,
    18:0.06,
    19:0.08,
    20:0.04,
    21:0.04,
    22:0.13,
    23:0.01,
    24:0.09,
    25:0.03,
    26:0.03,
    27:0.08,
    28:0.01,
    29:0.03,
    30:0.03,
    31:0.03,
    33:0.05,
    35:0.01,
    36:0.03,
    38:0.02,
    39:0.01,
    41:0.01,
    42:0.01,
    45:0.01
}
```

The prediction in this case should be closer to `26`. But if I use the mean I get `28.04`, which is not bad, but I'm quite certain there's a more sane way to calculate this without using just means given the underlying algorithm and the feeling the result is more like bell shaped.

Comment: How do you get total probability exceeding 1 (and by a long way)? If you have 90% chance of one outcome, all other - mutually exclusive - outcomes should add to 10%, shouldn't they? (Either that or you left out something important in your question.)

Comment: You're right, the data I was looking at was beyond corrupted, sorry. I've just edited the question with correct data and calculations.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a distribution, and want to turn it into a point estimate.  The mean is certainly one way to do this, but there are many others.  To decide which method is best, you need to specify an error measure on the estimate, otherwise known as a loss function.  If the error measure is squared error, then the mean is the optimal point estimate.

Your question also seems to ask if there is a better choice of distribution than putting a point mass at each of the given values.  Naïve Bayes by itself doesn't specify how one should interpolate these values, so you would have to apply some density estimator.   For example, a kernel density estimator or interpolation of the empirical CDF.  But I don't think there is much to gain from this.